# two random points on a unit square

Tags: probability

Assume you have a unit square and you select 2 points at random (uniformly).  Then turn the square, if you have to, so that one point is "southwest" of the other (so if you connect the points you have a line sloping up, left to right).  The expected Manhattan distance between the two points is 2/3.  Now start over, this time you generate one point at random.  Draw horizontal and vertical axes from that point.  Now to end up with the same upward sloping configuration, your second point needs to be either in Quadrant 1 or Quadrant 3 relative to your first point.  So generate one point randomly (uniformly) from that (two-rectangle) area.  Now connect your two points with an upward sloping line.  The expected Manhattan distance between these two points is a little less than 2/3.  Why are they different?

Answer (score 1):

That’s a nice question.

They’re different because you’re no longer uniformly sampling the points.

You’d get the same expected Manhattan distance as in your first experiment if instead of rotating configurations with lines sloping down you’d reject them and sample only from configurations with lines sloping up. But that’s not what you’re doing in the second experiment. You’re uniformly choosing a point and then forcing it to be the endpoint of a line sloping up. But the endpoints of lines sloping up are not uniformly distributed. A point near the upper left corner would be sampled very rarely if you sample only from configurations with lines sloping up, since the lines to most other points slope down. But you’re making it equally likely that that point is chosen as any other point.

Comment: ok right so by doing the experiment the way I did it, the "first" endpoint chosen is uniformly distributed, but in fact NEITHER endpoint of randomly chosen upward sloping lines (using e.g. the reject method) is actually distributed uniformly.  And neither is the distribution of both together (bottom or top endpoints of some upward sloping line).  I think that's the subtlety i was missing, thanks!